# Converting ColdFusion Struct to XML

Tags: xml, struct, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion struct which I'd like to convert into XML. I know of no native functions that are capable of converting the struct accordingly... I don't need to alter node names, they can take on the form of the respective object's classes and properties...

How exactly could this be done with ColdFusion?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If there is nothing in the CF documentation, the next place I always look is http://cflib.org . A quick search turned up [toXML()](http://cflib.org/udf/toXML) which sounds like it would do the trick. Give it a whirl.

Comment: `<cfwddx>` converts data to XML. (You might not like its format)

Comment: @ScottStroz Why even question my decision on what I need regarding my code? FYI, I'm dumping a configuration structure for easy portability...

Comment: Because I have seen enough times where someone needs help with their solution to a problem, but, in reality, they need a better solution. I was not questioning your decision, rather, I am trying to figure out what problem your decision is meant to solve. I would suggest that given the use case, XML might not be the best alternative, for reasons as you have discovered, there is no easy way to convert a structure into XML. I would suggest you try using JSON instead and use `serializeJSON()` and `deserializeJSO(N()` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColdFusion does not support this natively because unlike JSON there are a number of ways to convert data in CF into XML.

Usually it shouldn't be that hard to just loop and output xml inside `<cfxml>` tag to construct the XML object.  This is the most correct way of constructing XML and it guarantees the resulting XML is valid XML.

This is what ColdBox uses: XMLConverter ([Doc](http://apidocs.ortussolutions.com/ColdBoxDocs-3.8.1/coldbox/system/core/conversion/XMLConverter.html) / [Github](https://github.com/ColdBox/coldbox-platform/blob/master/system/core/conversion/XMLConverter.cfc))

Answer (score 0):

You can loop and use < cfxml > or XmlNew inside < cfscript >.

Reference here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-u-z/cfxml.html